# Enable a template depending on whether a certain function exists

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++14, sfinae

I would like to design a template that automatically provides an `operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&)` for all classes `T` for which `T::print_to(std::ostream&)` exists and can be called, so that I can define the printing function as a member function (and, in particular, take advantage of virtual calls).

Through trial and error, I managed to arrive at this:

```
template<typename T, typename = decltype(std::declval<T>().print_to(std::declval<std::ostream&>()))>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &s, const T &t) {
    t.print_to(s);
    return s;
}
```

It seems to be working, but since I am still new to SFINAE and this kind of tricks, would like to know if there is any pitfall or enhancement that can be made. I put a small test bench at https://ideone.com/uLJxac.

If possible, I would like to have a C++14 solution, because I am working with a C++14 code base. However, if using C++17 allows for a better solution, than I am also interested to that one.

Comment: @Glovanni Mascellani Actually you are trying to detect a ```concept```... [Constraints and concepts (since c++20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) and [Constraints and concepts (TS)
](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/constraints) will worth a look. For ```C++17``` and ```C++14``` ```concept```, have a look at my answer.

Comment: Why `typename = decltype` is needed here, I tried to remove it and nothing changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

There is no pitfall with your code, sorry about that. But this answer enables you to write code more like `C++20` `concept`:

```
template <class T>
auto& operator << (std::ostream &out, const printable_t<T> &t)
{
    t.print_to(out);
    return out;
}
```

In fact, I wrote a `C++17` [concept_check](https://github.com/NobodyXu/concept_check) library based on `detector` and can be used in this way.

For more info on `concept` support in `C++20`, have a look at these 2:[Constraints and concepts (since c++20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) and [Constraints and concepts (TS)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/constraints)

Original answer:

[std::experiment::is_detector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) can do the magic for you. Though it is not in standard library, it is not difficult to implement and that link gives the suggested implementation.

Here I will give you how to detect that function along with my implementaion of `is_detected_v`.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <ostream>

// For support for C++17 is not complete in many compiler, I also define void_t
template <class...> using void_t = void;

namespace impl {
template <class Default, class AlwaysVoid, template <class...> class Op, class ...Args>
struct detector: private std::false_type
{
    using std::false_type::value;
    using type = Default; 
};   
template <class Default, template <class...> class Op, class ...Args>
struct detector<Default, void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...>: private std::true_type
{
    using std::true_type::value;
    using type = Op<Args...>;
}; 
} // namespace impl

struct nonsuch {};

#define CONCEPT_T constexpr const static inline bool
template <template<class...> class Op, class ...Args>
CONCEPT_T is_detected_v = impl::detector<nonsuch, void, Op, Args...>::value;

// Detect whether print_to exists.    
template <class T>
using print_to_ret_t = decltype( std::declval<T>().print_to( std::declval<std::ostream&>() ) );

template <class T>
CONCEPT_T has_func_print_to_v = is_detected_v<print_to_ret_t, T>;

template <class T, std::enable_if_t< has_func_print_to_v<T> >>
using printable_t = T;

#undef  CONCEPT_T
```

You can try to add `C++14` support to this code. It won't be too difficult. The `CONCEPT_T`must be changed to `constexpr const static bool` to adjust to `C++14`.

Comment: Sorry but... why do you say that the Giuseppe's SFINAE implementation is wrong? It seems correct to me.

Comment: @max66 You are right...sorry for the misleading claim.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that your applying SFINAE correctly in your `operator<<()`; I don't see pitfalls in your solution.

I propose another version (C++11 compatible, so also C++14) just because require less typewriting

```
template <typename T>
auto operator<< (std::ostream & s, T const & t)
   -> decltype( t.print_to(s), s )
 {
   t.print_to(s);

   return s;
 }
```

Comment: This version is really neat and suits ```concepts``` that is only used once or twice.